# Where can a skilled and upper middle class US citizen work?

Tags: working-visas, foreign-employment

I recently overheard people discussing, "if (X person) became president they would move to Y".

I recognize it ignores the privilege americans have in traveling and is insensitive to the many refuge crises etc, but it got me thinking, and I was wondering where those people could actually work.

I was reading this question: [What countries are easy for a US citizen to move to?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/3281/what-countries-are-easy-for-a-us-citizen-to-move-to)

I've seen a few questions / answers like that but they tend to pertain to study/work, very low qualifications such as the above question, etc. I'm hoping for a slightly more specific to the people I've seen say that they will move. I'm essentially looking for a list of nations (if any) that the people who express those sentiments would be allowed to work / live in. As in is it feasibly and where could they go?

Example Scenario:

```
US Citizen
No ancestral connection to the country they're trying to move to
No criminal issues / debt / etc (nothing derogatory)
Single (no need to move a family etc)
mid 20's (I heard something about age being limited on some visas)
Well compensated (low six figures) STEM profession in US at top company
Bachelors STEM degree from good US university
Cash assets let's say 3-400k
Assume companies in the country would be willing to hire said person
```

From my experience I've previously been offered positions in Canada / England and told that work visas wouldn't be a problem etc. Is that true, I wasn't sure if the recruiters were just saying that (I know US ones do sometimes)? Where else would it not be a problem?

Some of my friends who are US citizens work abroad but they have familial ties to those countries.

Please ignore the probable changes in income / taxes / etc. But if you have insights into changes in quality of life of a country (ex STEM has a low value and job opportunities would be low if at all) if you know any. Also please state if the country requires a company sponsorship to enter, or any other insights. Example country 1 will let any well off american in with at least 100k, or country 2 will only allow those with company sponsorship in, or country 3 offers 2 months to find a job etc.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I voted to close as "too broad."